# Convert to Fast Enumeration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, performance, nsarray, enumeration

I have this traditional for loop that I want to convert to fast enumeration. How can I do this? Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_objects count]; i++)
{
    schedule = [[JSSchedule alloc] initWithDictionary:_objects[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
for (id object in _objects)
{
    schedule = [[JSSchedule alloc] initWithDictionary: object];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
for(NSDictionary *object in _objects)
{
    schedule = [[JSSchedule alloc] initWithDictionary: object];
}
```